# SSIS tables up to date with production

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have multiple MSSQL production databases from which i have to extract some data in a Data Warehouse. I have to keep DW tables up to date to have the same data as tables from production environment.

I am having trouble understanding how to keep data up to date in DW. 
I don't have Enterprise Edition to use CDC, and i am not sure what mechanism should i use.
I read about methods using `snapshot isolation` with `MERGE` statement, triggers, but i am not sure what to use.

Basically, i have about 15 instances, from each of them i need to load 2 tables in DW. 
The end users may request different ranges of data, for example one user requests data for the current hour, another for the last 24h, so i have to have a sync between production data and DW.

I hope the explanation can help you.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try to use replication with real low latency,but in your case since you need data from 15 instances,you might have to configure replication with push model as it reduces the distributor over head on DW

Comment: Further provide versions of sql you are using

Comment: Sorry, I use SQL Server 2008R2 and 2014.

Comment: I have Express Edition on some instances from where i need to get data to replicate but it can't serve as a publisher. Any workarounds?

Comment: One Custom solution could be to use After,delete,insert triggers on two tables to populate data into local tables and use a custom job or c# code to dump data into DW tables every 1 hour or as per your needs

Comment: That's the path i am working on :), i hope it doesn't have a big impact on performance. I also tried Change Tracking, but i didn't manage to find a way to get the modified data in DW in real time. Thanks for your thoughts!